# How to display proper image in CSS without mentioning height

Tags: html, css

I want to display image through CSS. But it is not displaying correctly. Can anyone help me to know that how can we display full size image in our browser without giving dam height property.

Thanks in advance.

Here is my markup:

```
<div class="Main_Content">
    <div class="Slider">
    </div>
```

Here is the CSS (not working)

```
.Main_Content {
    width: 100%;
}

.Slider {
    background-image: url("Construction%20Company/Stock%20Images/MG_5194-e1348062448312.jpg");
    display: flex;
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    position: unset;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: If by full size you imply that the containing div should match the size of the image without explicitly setting its height, then you must use the `<img>` tag instead of the `background-image` prop.

Comment: else give a look at background-size, where image can be resized with proper ratio. image in bg are meaning less in a document where they can only be part of design.

Comment: Do you want a full image background on your entire webpage?

Answer (score 3):

```
.Slider {
background-size:cover;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Will do the job. It will try to make the images as big until it reaches fullscreen.

See [background-size property on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Without using height use,

```
<img>
```

tag. This will definitely solve your issue.